# Stack around the variable was corrupted

Tags: c++, c

Извиняюсь за говнокод, но никак не пойму в чем дело. Выходит ошибка, НО! она появляется только при определенной последовательности действий.

Итак, эта программа должна определять правильно введенный номер карты (16 цифр)
Проверяет на длину и на содержание в строке посторонних символов.

```
Порядок действий:
1) вводим много раз разные буквы/цифры длиной не 16 символов
2) вводим несколько раз набор символов 16 символов
3) вводим набор 16 цифр!
```

Происходит ошибка Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'cardnumb' was corrupted.
Из-за чего ошибка?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char cardnumb[17];
    bool flag;
    do {
        cout<<"nomer karti: ";
        cin>>cardnumb;
        flag = 0;
        if (strlen(cardnumb)!=16)
        {
            cout<<"nepravilnaia dlina\n";
            flag = 1;
            continue;
        }
            for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
                if (!(cardnumb[i] == '0' || cardnumb[i] == '1'|| cardnumb[i] == '2'|| cardnumb[i] == '3'|| cardnumb[i] == '4'|| cardnumb[i] == '5'|| cardnumb[i] == '6'|| cardnumb[i] == '7'|| cardnumb[i] == '8'|| cardnumb[i] == '9'))
                {
                    flag = 1;
                }
                if (flag)
                    cout<<"nepravilnii vvod nomera\n";
        } while(flag);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char cardnumb[17];` — это ужасно. Что произойдёт, если пользователь введёт больше символов? Затрётся случайная переменная в стеке — это самое лучшее; по стандарту наверняка вовсе UB.

Используйте `std::string`.

```
while (true)
{
    cout << "Enter card no: ";
    string cardnumb;
    cin >> cardnumb;
    flag = 0;
    if (cardnumb.length() != 16)
    {
        cout << "must have 16 characters\n";
        continue;
    }

    bool isCorrect = true;
    for (char c : cardnumb)
        if (!isdigit(c))
            isCorrect = false;

    if (isCorrect)
        break;

    cout << "wrong number\n";
}
```

Или лучше проверять на цифры при помощи стандартных функций:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

...

bool isCorrect = all_of(cardnumb.begin(), cardnumb.end(), ::isdigit);
if (isCorrect)
    break;
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/VjgVpV

Comment: har cardnumb[17]; — это ужасно. Теперь понял в чем ошибка. Буду использовать fgets без всяких STL

Comment: @neko69: Странная идея. Возможности, аналогичные `fgets`, вы могли получить, использовав манипулятор `setw`: `cin >> setw(sizeof cardnumb) >> cardnumb;`. Но в вашем случае проще воспользоваться `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

Использование оператора `operator >>` с символьными массивами небезопасно. Скорее всего именно это является причиной порчи стека.

Вместо оператора `operatgor >>` с символьными массивами используйте стандартную функцию член класса `std::basic_istream` `getline`.

Например

```
std::cin.getline( cardnumb, sizeof( cardnumb ) );
```

Другая возможность - это использовать класс `std::string` вместо символьного массива.

Вместо этого длинного условия в `if` предложении

```
if (!(cardnumb[i] == '0' || cardnumb[i] == '1'|| cardnumb[i] == '2'|| cardnumb[i] == '3'|| cardnumb[i] == '4'|| cardnumb[i] == '5'|| cardnumb[i] == '6'|| cardnumb[i] == '7'|| cardnumb[i] == '8'|| cardnumb[i] == '9'))
```

вы могли бы написать просто

```
if ( cardnumb[i] < '0' || cardnumb[i] > '9' )
```

Стандарт C++ гарантирует, что все символы цифр расположены подряд без пропусков.

Так как вы используете функцию `strlen`, вам следует включить заголовок `<cstring>`.

Comment: `getline` в любом случае хорошая идея, т. к. юзер может вбить и пробелы

Comment: про "Вместо этого длинного условия в if предложении" - знаю, но хотелось написать свой костыльный код:)